# Close keyboard on tapping on Enter

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, silverlight-toolkit

I use the toolkit for Windows Phone 8 and have a page with a AutoCompleteBox.

Now I want to close the keyboard if user  writes something into the AutoCompleteBox without selecting a present item (meens user typed in a different text) and commits the text with "Return".

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this,

```
<AutoCompleteBox Name="Input" KeyUp="Input_KeyUp" FontSize="40">
        <AutoCompleteBox .InputScope>
            <InputScope>
                <InputScopeName />
            </InputScope>
         </AutoCompleteBox .InputScope>
  </AutoCompleteBox >
```

And on event,

```
private void Input_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        this.Focus();
    }
}
```

Read whole article here : [`Dismiss the SIP (keyboard) in WP8`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2010/07/02/programmatically-dismiss-the-sip-keyboard-in-windows-phone-silverlight-app.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can close the keyboard using a KeyUp event handler and then selecting Focus() of the current page:

```
void textBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // if the enter key is pressed
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        // focus the page in order to remove focus from the text box
        // and hide the soft keyboard
        this.Focus();
    }
}
```